# How to show/hide div using ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

At the moment I can click on button to get data and show div with comment replies, something like on Youtube, but I want to make it disappear by clicking again. Is this possible this way?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showReplies").click(function () {
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("data-href"),
            type: 'get',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(id)
                $(`#${id}.replies`).html(data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I tried to add display: none and then change it to block, or setting value='show/hide' and then use toggle('show') but it doesn't work. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can add ` $(`#${id}.replies`).html(''");` to the first line inside the click listener?

Comment: Right under `$(".showReplies").click(function () {`? Didn't help.

Comment: After `let id = $(this).attr('id');`. Well I added a small example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".showReplies").click(function () {
      let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $(`#${id} .replies`).html("Loading..");

      setTimeout(() => {
        $.ajax({
          url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`,
          type: 'get',
          success: function (data) {
              $(`#${id} .replies`).text(JSON.stringify(data));
          }
        })
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1">
  <div class="replies"></div>
  <button class="showReplies" data-id="1">Load Replies</button>
</div>


<div id="2">
  <div class="replies"></div>
  <button class="showReplies" data-id="2">Load Replies</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but in your example data doesn't disappear after clicking button again and that is what I want to achieve.

Comment: The code is just fine. The API I used was too fast and loaded so quickly. I've introduced a delay in the code using setTimeout, now you should see the changes happen.

Comment: Again: I have button "show replies", when I click on it replies show in div and lets say button changes to "hide replies" and when I click on it again the div disappears and button is "show replies" again. I hope you understand and maybe know solution :)

Comment: I found kind of solution. I added `$(`#${id}.replies`).toggle();` right under `let id = $(this).attr('id');`, but I have another problem: when I click on the button first, the console prints data but div doesn't show immediately. Until I click it again it shows and hides properly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a example, but your code looks wrong. it does not make sense to me.

```
beforeSend: function(data) { 
                $("#hideID").hide();
           },              
           success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(id)
            $(`#${id}.replies`).html(data);
        }
```

Comment: What is wrong in your opinion?
I found kind of solution. I added $(#${id}.replies).toggle(); right under let id = $(this).attr('id');, but I have another problem: when I click on the button first, the console prints data but div doesn't show immediately. Until I click it again it shows and hides properly.